# Cannot extract all the values from the parsed JSON in Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

Its seems that I cannot extract  all the values from from JSON. I can see the output just fine but I cannot put it in a array to present it in labels.
What is it that Im doing wrong?

```
struct EfectivO: Codable {        
   public var counted: Int
   public var registered: Int
}

struct TotalsByPaymentType: Codable {
  public var Efectivo: EfectivO
}

struct Results: Codable {
    var locale: String
    var date: String
    var totalsByPaymentType: TotalsByPaymentType
}

struct Loan: Codable {
  var results: [Results]
  var petitions: [Loan] = []
}


do {
   let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode(Loan.self, from: data)
   for item in courses.results {
     self.petitions.append(courses.self)
     print(item)
   }
   return
 } catch let jsonErr {
    print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
    return
 }
```

I havent post the raw JSON but I can see that there correct response. 
This is actual JSON:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "locale": "GB",
            "date": "2020-01-29",
            "totalsByPaymentType": {
                "Efectivo": {
                    "counted": 108130,
                    "registered": 106135
                },
                "Tarjeta de Credito": {
                    "counted": 209720,
                    "registered": 209720
                },
                "Cheque Gourmet": {
                    "counted": 1800,
                    "registered": 1800
                },
                "Ticket Restaurantes": {
                    "counted": 3800,
                    "registered": 3800
                },
                "Resto-In": {
                    "counted": 0,
                    "registered": 0
                },
                "Sodexo": {
                    "counted": 1921,
                    "registered": 1921
                },
                "Friend": {
                    "counted": 0,
                    "registered": 0
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can seem its very complicated structure and I have a nice response.

Comment: Logically `petitions` cannot be `[Loan]` if the root object is `Loan` and `append(courses.self)` looks pretty weird anyway.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The root is has just a single array that is [Loan].

Comment: You need [Loan] even if it single array, you can use Loan if its an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The root is has just a single array that is [Loan]

- turns out this is *not* what you have. Your JSON is a top-level object with one property `results`, which contains an array of objects. Also, the data structure does not look like it's recursive, as the data model in your question suggests.

Given the example JSON, you could either name each of the results explicitly, like so:

```
struct Results: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let locale, date: String
    let totalsByPaymentType: TotalsByPaymentType
}

struct TotalsByPaymentType: Codable {
    let efectivo, tarjetaDeCredito, chequeGourmet, ticketRestaurantes,
        restoIn, sodexo, friend: Total

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case efectivo = "Efectivo"
        case tarjetaDeCredito = "Tarjeta de Credito"
        case chequeGourmet = "Cheque Gourmet"
        case ticketRestaurantes = "Ticket Restaurantes"
        case restoIn = "Resto-In"
        case sodexo = "Sodexo"
        case friend = "Friend"
    }
}

struct Total: Codable {
    let counted, registered: Int
}
```

or collect all the payment totals in a dictionary:

```
struct Results: Codable {
    let results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let locale, date: String
    let totalsByPaymentType: [String: Total]
}
```

Which approach to use depends on how dynamic the "payment types" values change. Is it a fixed list? Then go for properties. Does is change every couple of weeks or months? Then use a dictionary.

In any case, you parse that using

```
do {
  let results = try JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: data)
  for result in results.results {
    // handle each result
  }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

(NB you should probably avoid generic names like `Result` in this case, but I don't understand your use case well enough to make appropriate suggestions)

Comment: Hi Gereon, thanx for response. I updated my question but I hace a follow up question. Should I assign variable to  to each key?

Comment: I wasnt using some of the values, but thank you for clearing this up.